# logout API facebook, twitter, linkedin

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, ios4, twitter, linkedin-api

I have code for logout for facebook twitter and linkedin

facebook

```
[facebookObj logout:self];
```

Twitter

```
[twitterObj endUserSession];
```

LinkedIn

```
static NSString *const kOAuthInvalidateTokenURL    = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken";

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:kOAuthInvalidateTokenURL];
return [self sendAPIRequestWithURL:url HTTPMethod:@"GET" body:nil];
```

but nothing is logout
I got error for facebook i.e

```
2011-04-11 19:18:03.820 myApp[2544:207] fbDidLogout
2011-04-11 19:18:07.303 myApp[2544:207] Request 01E3CA03-1671-49B4-95A7-E87081F68333 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"
```

Please guide me how we logout

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a request with the token and this url. You wil get status code 200.

Comment: I want logout from all of three... for which you are suggesting